# Android Studio searchiew icon not appearing

Tags: java, android

I am quite new to android studio.
I was trying to come up with a search view for my current project.

I am expecting that the search icon remains at the top of the app. However, when i run the simulator it doesn't appear.

[the draft in android studio code/design interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRTZU.png)

[What is shown in the emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7M9G.png)

I have searched for solutions online, changing the ListView Height to discrete dp instead of "match_parent", changing the menu item app:ShowAsAction to "ifRoom|collapseActionView" and "always". It doesnt change anything. I am very puzzled by this and hope that someone can help me with the issue.

Here is my code for the mainactivity.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="@android:color/black"
        android:dividerHeight="2dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
        tools:listitem="@android:layout/simple_list_item_1" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity java file

```
package com.example.test;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.view.MenuItemCompat;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //initialise variable
    ListView listView;
    ArrayList<String> carparkList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Assign variable
        listView = findViewById(R.id.list_view);

        //Add item in array list
        for (int i = 1; i <20; i++) {
            carparkList.add("Carpark" + i);
        }

        //Initialise adapter
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,carparkList);

        //Set adapter on list view
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //Display click item position in toast
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), adapter.getItem(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionMenu(Menu menu) {
        //Initialise menu inflator
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        //Inflate menu
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);
        //initialise menu item
        MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search_view);
        //Initialise searchview
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menuItem.getActionView();

        searchView.setQueryHint("Type your destination");

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                //filter array list
                adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                return false;
            }
        });
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}
```

and the menu_search.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/search_view"
        android:title="Search"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"/>
</menu>
```

Comment: replace `app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"` to `app:showAsAction="always"` in menu_search.xml

Comment: @Zain I have change the code but the search icon still does not appear ..

Answer (score 0):

In your menu XML file, try changing the showAction and ActionViewClass to this:

```
app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
    app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView "
```

You are referring to a different widget library in your Java code (android.widget.SearchView) than what is in your menu XML (androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView)

Then clean your project and rebuild it.

Its showing up in your emulator because it can identify the resource by ID but at runtime the ActionView is getting misled by another library.